# Retrieve and use Root-CA list of Microsoft or Mozilla and use it in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, truststore, root-certificate

The list of included root-CA certificates in OpenJDK for Windows is quite impressive but there are a lot of root-CA certificates that are trusted by common browsers like Firefox that are not trusted by Java.

Both [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2677070/an-automatic-updater-of-untrusted-certificates-is-available-for-window) and [Mozilla](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/nss/raw-file/default/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt) publish their current list of root-CA certificates but the used file format seems to be proprietary.

The curl project has an automatic converter that uses the Mozilla file as source, however this converter ([mk-ca-bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/mk-ca-bundle.html)) is a Perl script.

Is there a way to read one of these lists with plain Java so that it can be used as trust store afterwards?

Comment: I found an article describing the Microsoft format: http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=259

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK describes how they build the `cacerts` file in the [Security files for OpenJDK repo](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/tree/master/security). The script downloads the certificates from Mozilla:

```
wget https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/tip/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt .
```

As per the repo instructions you could build your own `cacerts` file that will trust another list of certificates of your own choosing:

> 1. Download the following Perl script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curl/curl/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl
> 2. Download the following Java application: https://github.com/use-sparingly/keyutil/releases/download/0.4.0/keyutil-0.4.0.jar (source available at https://github.com/use-sparingly/keyutil)
> 3. Run the provided `GenerateCertsFile.sh` script with: bash `./GenerateCertsFile.sh` - this will use the above files assuming they're located in the same directory as the script
> 4. Use the cacerts provided: it must be in the `jdk/jre/lib/security` or `jdk/lib/securityfolder`

Comment: As I wrote in my question the script is Perl - a language that is not available on a common Windows system. I am looking for a plain Java solution.

Comment: You can skip the Perl script part by using the PEM file located [here](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html).