# How to access a valid Oracle page through https with Jersey client?

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, truststore

I have been surprised to observe that the code `ClientBuilder.newBuilder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build().target("https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/naming-conventions.html").request().get();` throws a “Read timed out” exception using the Jersey JAX-RS client implementation. (When I tried to [report this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4673), I was told that it is not a bug.)

I expected that Jersey would use the default Java truststore, and that the default Java truststore would include CA certificates that permit to trust Oracle’s (and many other) website.

Indeed, running `keytool -list -cacerts`, I see that my truststore contains 166 certificates. I suppose that some of them permit to validate Oracle’s website, but I do not know how I can check that (well, apart from doing exactly what I am trying to do with Jersey).

I realize that I can download Oracle’s certificate and add it to my truststore, but I obviously do not want to do this for every classical web site out there to which I would like to connect using SSL. I would rather like to understand which web sites are supposed to be trusted by default in a “normal” Java installation (is there an official documentation about this somewhere?); how I can check whether my specific installation has some problem that prevents Oracle’s web site to be trusted; or, if it is normal, whether I can tell Java once and for all to trust the web sites that, say, Firefox or Chromium would trust by default.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56494335), for example, suggests that OpenJdk (which is what I use) should trust by default the same web sites as Firefox. And Firefox obviously trusts Oracle.

What am I missing?

**Edit** I realize it seems relevant to specify that I use Debian stable, as this issue might be OS-specific. I wonder if there’s something going wrong on my installation. “As far as I'm aware every distro patches OpenJDK to use its own list, which I guess is why this issue hasn't got much attention on GNU/Linux systems” -- [Andrew Haley on OpenJDK ML](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2020-May/004316.html). “Debian has tooling to create a cacert file from the system‘s keystore. There is a hook system that updates the cacert every time the system‘s keystore is changed. lib/security/cacert is actually a symlink to that file. (…) In case of Debian, it‘s identical with Mozilla‘s list.” -- [aahlenst on GH Adoptium issue](https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/13#issuecomment-622099489). Indeed: `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/security/cacerts` reveals that it links to
`/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`.